# i can't fill my gridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

In my project , i have 2 windows forms and 1 gridview contains 5 columns (name gridv)
I want to fill 4 columns from forms1 and the 5th columun from the forms2
but i can't do it (error in my appli execution )

my code (how to fill the 5th column)

```
Dim selectrow As Integer = Form1.gridv.CurrentRow.Index ' selectrow mean selected row indice 
        MessageBox.Show("ligne selectionnée : " & Convert.ToDouble(selectrow))
        Form1.gridv.Rows.Add(corp_mail.Text = Form1.gridv.Item(4, selectrow).Value) ' fill the 5th column`
```

Comment: where you fill the columns

Comment: in gridview ( 4 columns from form1 et the 5th from form2)
I explain ,in the form1 (i want to send mail ) and save the data in gridview (grid contain idmail , adress , subject , and body_send)
the form 2 (respond to mail ) and save the body_respond in gridview
in the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the error but from what information you have given this is what your code is doing:

1. evaluates if `corp_mail.Text` is equal to the value of the 5th column of the selected row. This is a true or false, not a string.
2. Adds (or tries to) a new row to the grid with true or false as the value of the first cell.

If I understand correctly, this is what you want to do:

```
Form1.gridv.Item(4, selectrow).Value = corp_mail.Text
```

This will set the value of the 5th column of the selected row.

Although you mention a second grid on another form, not a textbox, so you probably have more work to do. But the idea is the same, instead of the TextBox value get the value from the other grid.

Comment: when i execute my application , the 5th column in grid stay empty and a new row add and the first column ( in new row ) it is  written "false"

Comment: That is exactly what I said.

Comment: before creating another grid , i try this code and the result is the 5th column in grid stay empty and a new row add and the first column ( in new row ) it is written the correct text

code (in the second form)
        Form1.gridv.Rows.Add(t1.Text)

Comment: `Rows.Add()` will add a row. That's why the method was named "Add". I gave you the code you can use to set the value of a cell in an an existing row.